# Angular 2 determine state based on element class

Tags: angular, animation, transition, angular-animations, angular-transitions

I have carousel in Angular 2 and I want to add transitions to it. I did [Tour of Heroes](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/) tutorial and so I have in app.component.ts:

```
<carousel [interval]="5000" [noWrap]="noLoopSlides">
      <hero *ngFor="let hero of heroes; let index=index" [active]="hero.active" [inactive]="hero.inactive" class="item fill">
        <img [src]="hero.image" style="margin:auto;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3 style="background-color: transparent;color: white;">Slide {{index + 1}}</h3>
        </div>
      </hero>
    </carousel>
```

and the class of hero element changes from `item fill carousel-item active` to `item fill carousel-item inactive` with time interval and only the `active` one is displayed. I would like to make the transition from `active` to `inactive`, but based on [Documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html) I need to use trigger `[@heroState]="hero.state"`. Is there a way, to change state based on class?

Comment: You can't describe three states (active, inactive, inTransition) with booleans (true/false)... You could try using `[ngClass]="hero.state"` and update your code so `hero.state` can hold more then two (active/inactive) values...

Comment: Yes, I do understand that although is there a way of saying `if active==True then hero.state = active`, otherwise `hero.state = inactive`?

Comment: `hero.state = active === true ? 'active' : 'inactive'` maybe?